# How to learn how many bytes were received via I2C using the STM32 HAL?

Tags: stm32, i2c, hal

I'm successfully reading bytes, as an I2C slave, using the STM32 HAL.

How can I tell how many bytes were received before the STOP?

I currently read the received data with an implementation of:

```
void HAL_I2C_ListenCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c) {
    const uint8_t register_to_write = rx_buffer[0];
    const uint8_t * rx_data = rx_buffer + 1;
    ...
}
```

Where I read from the `rx_buffer` which I earlier gave to:

```
HAL_I2C_Slave_Seq_Receive_IT(&hi2c1, rx_buffer, RX_BUFFER_SIZE, I2C_FIRST_FRAME)
```

Comment: A cheap approach can be a buffer array filled with dummy values that you definitely can't receive. Like if your receive buffer array is filled with 0x69 0x69 0x69 0x69, then after reception you can tell how many bytes were altered. Is that approach good enough, or you want some substantial change in the algorithm?

Comment: @Ilya Thanks, but I need to receive arbitrary binary data.  I can't imagine that there is no count of the bytes received, it's just how to find it in the HAL.

Comment: There is actually, as far as I know, no way to know. I2C peripheral doesn't have any counter. I have just checked STM32F746 reference manual, I2C section (and I wrote a primitive I2C bare metal driver a little while ago). Maybe you can make a counter that gets incremented by interrupt on every received byte (obviously, interrupt needs to be enabled only during reception).

Comment: Oh, that's a horrible API.  This must be why SMBus transfers have a length byte before the data.

Comment: Nothing to do with API. This is how I2C hardware works. Nobody sponsored a bunch of transistors to count bytes, it's not implemented physically, it's your job to implement it in software in a way that would work for you, although I can totally understand how handy it would be to just have an automatic counter. However, DMA can do all of that. DMA also has a counter to know how many bytes were transmitted/received.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I was VERY wrong. I2C CR2 control register 2 has "NBYTES" field I totally forgot about (just opened the register documentation). I think, you can use that field to tell how many bytes actually arrived. Without any DMA or interrupts. Want me to write a full answer on how to use that?

Comment: Thanks, that's enough of a clue for me to give it a try.  If you want to write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I2C CR2 (control register 2) has, among other things, NBYTES field

[image]

where SBC is "Slave Byte Control", which is set in I2C CR1, specifics of what it is are of course in the I2C section of the reference manual.

It looks like NBYTES is programmed with the number of bytes you expect to receive before the transmission happens. So if you provide 10-byte buffer for HAL, I would expect to see 10 in NBYTES field before physical communication begins. Thus, if you receive fewer bytes, it would be reasonable to expect "leftover" value in NBYTES - how many bytes were yet to receive after communication ended (logic identical to DMA counter). So if your receive buffer was of length 10, but after communication, NBYTES is, say, 4, then you received 10-4=6 bytes of data. Of course, it's your job to check how exactly HAL sets NBYTES and whether it nullifies it at the end of reception. But yes, in principle, it's totally doable.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The STM32 tracks how many bytes are free in the your buffer, rather than how many have been received.

Comment: Which is exactly what I showed in the made up example. It shows how many bytes are left to receive. So if your starting number was the length of the buffer (as it should be), then yes, you get the number of free spaces in the buffer.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was just highlighting that it was difficult to find in the debugger if you were looking for a value of "4" after sending four bytes.

Answer (score 0):

An easier to access variable is `XferCount`:

```
void HAL_I2C_ListenCpltCallback(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c)
{
    const size_t size = RX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1 - hi2c->XferCount;
    ...
```

In my case, `RX_BUFFER_SIZE == 33` and I see `hi2c->XferCount == 28` after receiving the sub-address/register-number byte and four bytes of data.

Comment: I take it XferCount points to the same exact NBYTES thing? (I'm not super proficient with HAL)

Comment: No, XferCount is not (obviously) a register.  It is modified (mostly decremented) in dozens of functions in the HAL.  The string "NBYTES" occurs nowhere in my ST CubeMX project.

Comment: It obviously isn't a register, I meant, it must be connected to that field (hold same value?). You can't have no NBYTES anywhere at all, because it's part of I2C spec. It's a must if you both write and read something, NBYTES is definitely set to something before each communication, the question is where and how. Must be deeper in there. But yeah, if this XferCount works, why not. Or maybe your MCU has different I2C implementation, but as far as I'm aware of, MCU peripherals of STM32 are usually either 100% identical or require a light touch at most.

Comment: In stm32f1xx_hal_i2c.h: `typedef struct __I2C_HandleTypeDef { I2C_TypeDef *Instance; /*!< I2C registers base address*/` and  `__IO uint16_t              XferCount;` so it looks like the I2C struct is an overlay for a set of registers.

Comment: HAL structs are not overlays. They're collection of parameters, and they aren't always exhaustive or presented in most logical fashion (at least, it's arguable), one of those variables is a pointer to the registers. The other are just independent variables. When you call HAL function, it takes some specific variables from that struct as arguments. Real overlay structs are CMSIS. It's there that you write I2C2->CR2 = ... and you have direct access to register. (that's how I write my stuff, after that understanding what libraries do is kinda easy, but initially it's really hard)